# Positive Integer Solutions to an Equation with Individual Variable Constraints

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of positive integer solutions to $ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 100 $ if $x_1 \le 30$, $x_2\le40$, $x_3\le50$, $x_4\le60$, and $x_5\le70$.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What have you tried?

Comment: i have calculated the solutions with Mathematica

Answer (score 0):

You can create the generating function

$$f(x)=(x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{30})(x+...+x^{40})(x+...+x^{50})(x+...+x^{60})(x+...+x^{70})=\\=x^5(1-x)^{-5}(1-x^{30})(1-x^{40})(1-x^{50})(1-x^{60})(1-x^{70})=\\=x^5\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{4+k}{4}x^k\right)(-x^{250} + x^{220} + x^{210} + x^{200} + x^{190} - x^{170} - 2 \, x^{160} - 2 \, x^{150} - 2 \, x^{140} + 2 \, x^{110} + 2 \, x^{100} + 2 \, x^{90} + x^{80} - x^{60} - x^{50} - x^{40} - x^{30} + 1)$$

So to know the number of ways to sum 100 with your conditions you must know the coefficient of the power 100 of the previous expression.

So you must solve and sum all of these equations where

$$100=5+k+R\to k=95-R$$

Where R are the powers of the polynomial after the summation, i.e, $R=\{0,30,40,50,60,80,90,100,110,140,150,160,170,190,200,210,220,250\}$

Because *k* only can take positive values the equation is reduced to $k=95-R^*$, where $R^*=\{0,30,40,50,60,80,90\}$. So

$$c(100)=\binom{99}{4}+2\binom{9}{4}+\binom{19}{4}-\sum_{j=0}^{3}\binom{10j+39}{4}=\\
=\frac{1}{24}((99)_4+(19)_4+2(9)_4-\sum_{j=0}^{3}(10j+39)_4)$$